# When to use beginUpdates() and endUpdates() in CarPlay

Tags: ios, swift, carplay

I'm currently developing a CarPlay audio app and I can't figure out where and when to use `MPPlayableContentManager.shared().beginUpdates()` and `MPPlayableContentManager.shared().endUpdates()`.

The Apple docs say that you should wrap any updated MPContentItem with `.beginUpdates()` and `.endUpdates()`. When I do that nothing is updated on CarPlay. I feel like I'm calling the functions in the wrong place.

Apple docs:

> If you are changing multiple items, or multiple properties of an item,
>   you should call MPPlayableContentManager beginUpdates prior to
>   updating MPContentItem objects and endUpdates after you have finished
>   updating them. That way, the items will refresh on the screen all at
>   once.

To me it sounds like I need to use `.beginUpdates()` and `.endUpdates()` in the response of an API request when I retrieve the data, but I'm not sure. Could someone please give an example of when to use both `.beginUpdates()` and `.endUpdates()` when updating content?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on Playable item to start NowPlaying screen it calls:

```
func playableContentManager(_ contentManager: 
MPPlayableContentManager, initiatePlaybackOfContentItemAt indexPath: 
 IndexPath, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)
```

In this function you have to use .beginUpdates() and .endUpdates(). In between this two you have to initialise:

```
self.infoCenter.nowPlayingInfo = self.setupNowPlayingInfo(for:  indexPath)
      completionHandler(nil)
```

This methods are used to Test CarPlay app in simulator mostly.

[Check this wwdc2018 from 10:15](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/213/)